# Android market filtering issue

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I have created an app that check if WIFI/GPS is enabled in a mobile phone along with some other data..
If WIFI is enabled then will do some action else it will skip that portion.. So this basically means that Availability of WIFI/GPS is not a requisite for my app..

But after uploading my app in the android market, it shows..

```
This apk requests 4 features that will be used for Android Market filtering

android.hardware.wifi
android.hardware.location
android.hardware.location.gps
android.hardware.touchscreen
```

All these 4 is not a requisite for my app.. then why its showing that my app will be filtered based on these..

Also if i set the  tag to false in my android manifest will my app be visible to all the phones especially those without touchscreen,wifi,gps and all???

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
```

Will my app be visible to all phones irrespective of any filtering if i set the  tag to false ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to set android:required to false.  What that tag means (when you set the attribute to false) is that your app *could* use that feature, but doesn't require that the phone have it to run - which is what you want, it sounds like.

Comment: in my app before this update which i am planning, i have used set the <use-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen> tag to false as my app can be run in non touch screen phones too,but all the entry which i got is from Touch Screen phones,not even a single non touch screen phone data i got..That's why i got doubtful of this tag

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, that's not a bad thing. If somebody wants an app that uses GPS, they won't filter against it.

If your app secretly uses GPS to track them, then they'll know their "Game" uses GPS so it works for them, and you'll get a bad review.